# Creating Calculator App in Windows Store

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am creating a Calculator in Windows Store Application. I have successfully created the app in the store.

Now there is a problem in my app, after getting the result from performing any operation whenever I press on any numeric value, that value got append in the existing value.

In the following snapshot: I have added two numbers (1,1):

[image]

Now I am entering another value to perform some other option, but the new value got append in the existing value. I am entering 1 here:

[image]

What is the code for removing the existing value, if any numeric values pressed?

Comment: You should show some code... as to how you are currently doing things.

Answer (score 0):

you could declare a bool value which is false and when you have your calculation done you switch it to true. Then you write a method that checks if the calculation is done or not and if it's done you simply clear the (i guess you use a textblock / box?) output. That would be my way in this situation - maybe there is a better solution for you. I hope it helps you to get a clearer way in mind.

Comment: I think this is salvageable if you can provide the actual code that implements your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the Windows Calculator that shipped from Windows 3.0 through Windows Vista, I agree with user3645029's response. You need to work out the input model for the app, so you understand clearly when you begin entering a new number and when you append to the one showing. I suspect that your app logic isn't making this distinction.

Let me be more specific:

- If the key pressed is a number and the last key pressed was a number, then you add that new digit, which effectively means multiplying the current value by 10 and then adding the new key.
- If the key pressed is a number and the last key pressed was an operator, =, or similar keys, then you're starting a new number input and your current value should be reset to 0 first.

In short, writing a calculator app requires an internal state machines that understands how to proceed from one input to the next. From what you describe, it sounds like you're missing the logic for the = key. Generally speaking, hand-held calculators with an = sign effectively clear the current value if you start entering a new number after =. Only if you press an operator does that value persist, and in that case you're also starting a new current value and keeping the "2" in your case as the first operand.